# Python socket setdefaulttimeout method not working

Tags: python, linux, sockets, geany, python-sockets

So, I was following a course to make a sort of port scanner with the socket module of python in geany, only to realize that the socket module was appearing as an error in my code, and that the socket.setdefaultimeout wasn't working, running my code inmedietly. I do not know why this happened.
I'm running python3 on a virtual machine of linux.

Here's the code:

```
 !/usr/bin/env python3

import sys #allows us to enter command line arguments
import socket 
from datetime import datetime



if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    target = socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1])
else: 
    print("Unvalid amount of arguments \nExample: 'python3 scanner.py <ip>'")
    sys.exit()
    
print("-" * 50)
print("Target is {}".format(target))
print("Starting time: {}".format(str(datetime.now())))
print("-" * 50)

try:
    for port in range(0, 85):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("Checking port {}".format(port))
        result = s.connect_ex((target, port))
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
        if result == 0:
            print("Port {} is open for ".format(port))
        s.close()
        
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    print("\n Exiting the program")
    sys.exit()
except socket.gaierror:
    print("Host name could not be resolved")
    sys.exit()
except socket.error:
    print("The server is down, could not connect to the server")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: exactly how is `socket.setdefaultimeout` not working?

Comment: Edit the question and specify the expected vs. actual behavior.